# How to test RSA keys for flaws in encryption

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

Recently I have read an article [Seriously, stop using RSA](https://blog.trailofbits.com/2019/07/08/fuck-rsa/)
and I was wondering what is the best way to test my implementation of the RSA keyset generation. I am not a security expert, but I have been working in Java and Software Dev. for quite some time now. However, I am not sure how I would test the strength of a key (flaws in the implementation process).

The Implementation I did for my RSA key gen is the following:

```
private KeyPairGenerator keyGen; 
private PrivateKey privateKey;
private PublicKey publicKey;
private SecureRandom srandom;


public SecreteKeyGenerator() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    this.keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    this.keyGen.initialize(Encryptable.RSA_LENGTH);

    this.srandom = new SecureRandom();
}

public void createRSAKeys() {
    KeyPair pair = this.keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    this.privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
    this.publicKey = pair.getPublic();
}
```

The way I am using this implementation is in combination with AES key. I use AES key to encrypt the data and then I encrypt the key using RSA. 
This is a suggested method in Java when dealing with large files.

The variable `Encryptable.RSA_LENGTH` has a value 2048, which is the length of a key. 
After the keys are generated they are written to a files stored on clients machine.

The encryption works properly, as well as the digital signature process. However, I want to be extra sure that I've implemented everything correctly.

This is the code that is handling the encryption process of the file:

```
public void execute() {
        OperationsLogger.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "Encryption of file started");
        AESEncryption aesEncryption = new AESEncryption();
        aesEncryption.createAESKey();
        aesEncryption.encryptFile(this.targetFilePath, this.publicKeyPath);
        OperationsLogger.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "File encrypted successfully.");
}


//AES Encryption
public void encryptFile(String inputFile, String publicKeyLocation) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(inputFile + ".enc")) {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new RSAEncryption().getPublic(publicKeyLocation));

        byte[] b = cipher.doFinal(secretKey.getEncoded());
        out.write(b);

        out.write(gen.getIv());

        Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        ci.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, gen.getIvspec());
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inputFile)) {
            processFile(ci, in, out);
        }
    }
}

   public PublicKey getPublic(String filename) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(new File(filename).toPath());
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return kf.generatePublic(spec);
    }
```

Comment: You are not generating the key - the crypto provider in Java runtime is. There's no RSA *implementation* in **your** code to speak of, just some calls to the Java provided one.

Comment: The article should've been called "Seriously, stop *reimplementing* RSA". You're not.

Comment: Ah, I see. So using Java's way of implementing RSA is considered safe. And you are right, with the title as is, it is possible to conclude that any RSA usage is bad.

Comment: You only show how you create the RSA key, not how you encrypt with the key. Not implementing the encryption correctly can lead to an insecure implementation. As the article mention RSA is insecure if you e.g don't use propper padding.

Comment: I'm not a fan of that article. To me it represents the worst of the dogmatic excesses that plague the profession. However, that is mostly a question of tone. The technical points are mostly valid.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen I have edited the post to reflect what you mentioned.

Comment: Still everyone, my question was how to test the key and possibly the encryption process??

Comment: I'm skeptical that "testing" for RSA flaws is viable. Not all the flaws even in that article can be tested for, and that article was not attempting to list every possible flaw. For example, you cannot really test that your primes are *globally* unique.

Comment: In the spirit of that article, don't aim for *testing* the implementation yourself, either  - that's a job best left for a cryptographer. Instead, do a literature search for papers on the same.